# Using super() in subclass and changing the 'contains' method accordingly

Tags: java, inheritance

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Cell extends Rectangle{

    int x;
    int y;

    public Cell(int x, int y) {
        super(x,y);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g, Boolean highlighted) {
        if (highlighted) {
            g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 35, 35);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x, y, 35, 35);
    }

    public boolean contains(Point target){
        if (target == null)
            return false;
        return target.x > x && target.x < x + 35 && target.y > y && target.y < y +35;
    }
}
```

I have changed the constructor for the class cell and used super() to link it to the parent class rectangle. However, I used to have a grid from this and the mains method but not anymore. How do I change the contains method to get back a grid when the program is run?

Comment: After reading all this I still have no clue what exactly your problem is. Please, provide actual - expected results

Comment: I need to use the contains method for a rectangle to achieve a grid like structure when my code is run but I'm not too sure how to change the current contains method to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The `Rectangle` class has already `x` and `y` fields.
Why do you extend this class and also add these fields in the subclass ?
`x` and `y` in the subclass hide which one of the super class.

For example here :

```
public Cell(int x, int y) {
    super(x,y);
}
```

You set `x` and `y` of the super class.

While here :

```
public boolean contains(Point target){
    if (target == null)
        return false;
    return target.x > x && target.x < x + 35 && target.y > y && target.y < y +35;
}
```

`x` and `y` refer to subclass fields that equals `0` as these were not valued in the constructor.

Remove them and use which one of the super class.